# If Statements in do-while Loop

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, do-while

I need to enter two numbers, where first is a initial number and the second is the amount of iteration. I need to check if number is buzz and if not skip it and check another one before I reach amount of iteration. Then I need to get 10 lines with buzz numbers.

I wrote the following code, but I don't get needed result.

```
import java.util.*;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] input = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
        
        int counter = 0;
        do {
            String nextNumber = String.valueOf(Long.parseLong(input[0]) + counter);
            if (isBuzz(Long.parseLong(nextNumber)) == true) {
                System.out.println("\t" + (nextNumber + " is " + "+"));
                counter++;
            }
        } while (counter < Long.parseLong(input[1]));
    }
    
    public static boolean isBuzz(long number) {
        boolean isDivisible = number % 7 == 0;
        boolean endsWith7 = String.valueOf(number).endsWith("7");
        return isDivisible || endsWith7;
    }
}
```

I think the problem is in if statement, because if I remove it the code works but it doesn't exclude numbers which are not a buzz.

Comment: What happens when the if statement is left in? Also isBuzz returns a boolean so writing your if statement `if(isBuzz(Long.parseLong(nextNumber))` would work fine

Comment: If I remove do-while I get expected result, when I'm entering one number which is buzz.

Comment: What happens if you leave the while in?

Comment: After first input, just empty line which is endless cycle of input.

Comment: you only increment counter within your if statement. if that if statement is false you never increment count and continue to check the same number forever. your `counter++;` should be outside of the if statement but within the while loop, see if that helps

Comment: Yes, this is it. Just need to create two counters, one inside if statement and second inside do-while cycle. First counts number of iteration and must be < than second input number, second uses just as increment which get us new value on each step of iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
int counter = 0;
int increment = 0;
do {
    String nextNumber = String.valueOf(Long.parseLong(input[0]) + increment);
    if (isBuzz(Long.parseLong(nextNumber))) {
        System.out.println("\t" + (nextNumber + " is " + "+"));
        counter++;
    }
    increment++;
} while (counter < Long.parseLong(input[1]));
```